# Can not see a push notification on GitHub after i push to the remote repository

Tags: git, github

After i commit and push to the remote repository from the command line:

```
git commit -m 'ID: XXXXXX Some comments'
git push origin feature/xxxxx
Everything up-to-date
```

But when i go to github, i can't see my push on the News Feed, something like `luca pushed to feature/xxxx at xxxxxxxxx`

I am obviously on the concerned branch, i checked with a `git branch` command.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git message `Everything up-to-date` indicates that the remote branch you are pushing to is already in sync with the local branch being pushed. Hence, there is no news feed on GitHub since nothing on the remote branch changed.

If your local branch is out of sync with the remote branch, then executing:

```
$ git status
```

will show a message such as the following:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

Now when you push the local branch to the remote branch, git displays a message such as:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:user/project.git
   d478973..abc3741  master -> master
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply, one question, does this mean it has been pushed successfully at least ?

Comment: @Luca: Yes, `Everything up-to-date` means that any outstanding changes that have been committed on the local branch have already been successfully pushed to the remote branch.

Comment: When i do `git status` i got this message : `On branch feature/xxxxxx
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: @Luca: Correct. When your working directory (current checked-out branch) is clean, then there are no uncommitted changes (hence, `nothing to commit`).

Comment: Thanx for these clarifications, i'll get back to you if something still unclear regarding this (please bear with me ^_^).